# How to complete rustup/cargo commands?

Tags: bash, rust, rust-cargo, bash-completion, rustup

I have rustup+rust+cargo installed using the [official installation script](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).

How do I enable shell completions, to be able to type `cargo <TAB>` in the terminal and see the possible commands such as `cargo check`?

Answer (score 19):

You can run `rustup completions` and follow the instructions. For example, for `bash` you can run

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions

rustup completions bash       > ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/rustup
rustup completions bash cargo > ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/cargo
```

to generate completions for `rustup` and `cargo` respectively. Consult `rustup completions` for further details, e.g. for configuring `zsh` and `fish` completions.

Answer (score 4):

This will keep the completion functions up to date.

```
bash$ cat ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/rust
if type -P rustup > /dev/null; then
    source <( rustup completions bash )          # for rustup
    source <( rustup completions bash cargo )    # for cargo
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

@AnonymousDuck's answer is a good way to do it in principle. A downside to "expanding" the completions is that one should remember to regenerate the expanded forms after updates, so they're kept up to date with the respective tools.

A way to make that happen on demand (sacrificing a few milliseconds on first invocation) is for example:

```
printf '. <(rustup completions bash)\n'       >~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/rustup
printf '. <(rustup completions bash cargo)\n' >~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/cargo
```

A slight caveat that is rarely an issue is that the use of `<(...)` requires the shell to *not* be in POSIX mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh), you can install the [`rust`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/rust) plugin to add completion for `rustc`, `rustup`, and `cargo`.
To do so, add `rust` to the plugins in your `.zshrc` file:

```
plugins=(... rust)
```